# Asset Pipeline Where are These Files Coming From

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, assets, pipeline

My Rails app is getting a couple resources, and I think I want it to ; )

The problem is, I need to understand where they are coming from, but I don't:

```
7.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2018:12:05:33 EST] "GET /assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 200 22344
http://localhost:3000/ -> /assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.css
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2018:12:05:33 EST] "GET /assets/jquery.timepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1584
http://localhost:3000/ -> /assets/jquery.timepicker.css
```

I gather that the assets pipeline is pulling them from somewhere, but I can't figure out from where. There are no files by these names anywhere that I can find in the assets (including vendor) folders or public. Is there a tool other way that I can understand where these are coming from?

Comment: Some gems add their own assets to the asset pipeline, including gems that come in the default rails Gemfile. Check your Gemfile and you'll have a better idea, or you can show us your Gemfile if you still can't figure out.

Comment: how does the top/header of `datepicker.css` looks like?

Comment: Tamer - I could never figure out what was happening, so I expect it is as you say. I expected that if the files come from the gems, I'd see that clearly in, for example, the vendor directory. But there is only a different file, jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css.  Maybe that gets transformed somehow to one of the above.  If you want to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Fabrizio - The issue was that I don't know where the files are coming from, so I can't look at them to tell you.